# How can i install google cloud sdk(gcloud cli) on docker container using pip?

Tags: docker, gcloud

How can i install google cloud sdk(gcloud cli) on docker container using pip ? Is it possible ?
I want to install gcloud sdk on Google Cloud Run docker container.

For example like this ⬇️ :

```
awscli==any version
gcloud-sdk???
```

**requirement.txt**

Comment: https://pypi.org has the official listing of all Python packages.  If you're looking for the CLI, the Google Cloud docs have [installation instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install) but it doesn't necessarily involve the Python-specific `pip` tool.

Answer (score 2):

Not with `pip`, but here is the recipe from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-apt-get

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list

apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg curl -y

curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -

apt-get update && apt-get install google-cloud-sdk -y
```

Depending on your use case you might then need to activate the service account key like:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=my-service-account-key.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with `pip`, but you can find detailed information to install the sdk here `https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb`